# Conversion date error in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

When executing the below dynamic SQL statement, I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

`[ReturnDate]` is defined as `datetime` and `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` parameters are being passed as type `datetime` as well. What am I missing ?

```
Set @SQLString = 
   'Select 
        [ID], [ReturnDate], [PolicyNumber]
    From 
        Bil_ReturnsRepository   
    Where
        (' + @PolicyNumber + ' is null or  PolicyNumber =  (' + @PolicyNumber + ')) 
        and (ReturnDate) >= Convert(date, ' + @FromDate + ')) 
        and (ReturnDate) <= Convert(date, ' + @ToDate + '))
        and PaymentAmount > 0.00'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The date functions are different for different dbms.  Tag your dbms if you want help.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  If so, learn to use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql).  One of its powers is the ability to pass in parameters:

```
Set @SQLString = '
Select [ID], [ReturnDate], [PolicyNumber]
From Bil_ReturnsRepository   
Where (@PolicyNumber is null or PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber) and
      (ReturnDate >= @p_FromDate) and
      (ReturnDate <= @p_ToDate) and
      PaymentAmount > 0.00
';

declare @p_fromdate date;
declare @p_todate date;

select @p_fromdate = convert(date, @fromdate),
       @p_todate = convert(date, @todate);

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@p_fromdate date, @p_todate date, @policynumber int',
                   @p_fromdate=@p_fromdate, @p_todate=@p_todate, @policynumber=@policynumber;
```

The variables `@p_fromdate` and `@p_todate` are not necessary if `@fromdate` and `@todate` already have the correct types.

Comment: will this work if for example the parameter policyNumber is a list ? I understand the sql would then change to PolicyNumber in  @PolicyNumber

Comment: @Jason . . . This follows your original logic, which also does not work if `@PolicyNumber` is a list.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate `string` with `datetime`, I would suggest you to
use `sp_executesql` to parameterize the dynamic sql

```
declare @SQLString  nvarchar(max)--should be nvarchar

Set @SQLString = 
   'Select 
   [ID]
  ,[ReturnDate]
  ,[PolicyNumber]
 From Bil_ReturnsRepository   
 Where
      (@PolicyNumber is null or  PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber) and
      ReturnDate >= @FromDate and
      ReturnDate <= @ToDate and
      PaymentAmount > 0.00'

exec sp_executesql @SQLString,
                   N'@FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime, @PolicyNumber int',
                   @FromDate, @ToDate, @PolicyNumber
```

By this way your query is much safer and cleaner without so many string concatenation.

**Note :** use appropriate datatype for `@PolicyNumber` in `sp_executesql`

Comment: could the PolicyNumber parameter be of type list<string> ? I want to pass multiple values to PolicyNumber so that the sql statement would retrieve all records with PolicyNumber in (@PolicyNumber)